# Angular Animation from void to state won't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I have the following animation:

```
trigger('EnterLeave', [
    transition('start => void', [
      animate('300ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
    ]),
    transition('void => stop', [
      state('void', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
      animate('300ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
    ]),
    transition('stop => void', [
      animate('300ms ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
    ])
  ]);
```

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="row mt-5" [@EnterLeave]="animation">
</div>

In .ts:
animation = 'stop';
```

The only transition not working is void => stop. I've also tried void => *, but this wouldn't work as well.

All I want is the content to come in from the left.

Does anyone see the issue here? I've tried to solve this for a while now.

Comment: You can use the Animation Start & Done Event to see what is happening behind the scenes inside your animation. This could might help you fixing your issue.  https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationEvent

Comment: Please provide us the event informations to be able to help you.